# how to get cookie from urlrequest in iOS wkwebview

Tags: ios, cookies, request

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    var req = navigationAction.request;
    let cookie = req.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie");
    print(cookie) // always nil

    decisionHandler(.allow);
}
```

I want to get the session after user login, but the cookie is always nil;how can I get it ?

Answer (score 3):

Cookie is generally stored in variable document.cookie in browser.
You can access it by executing Javascript code. In this case simply `"document.cookie"` would return the cookies.

```
   let cookieScript = "document.cookie;"
   webView.evaluateJavaScript(cookieScript) { (response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                    print(response as! String)
                }
   }
```

Comment: what if the cookie is http only?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use `WKWebView`'s API that appeared since iOS 11

```
webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies() { cookies in
    // do what you need with cookies
}
```

One advantage is that this method tracks HttpOnly cookies as well.

Comment: Because it doesn't work!